# Времена в русском языке

Tags: морфология, грамотность

Пытаюсь спроектировать морфологический парсер русского языка. И вот незадача ... Со школьной скамьи нам повествовали только о трех временах в русском языке: `будущем`, `настоящем` и `прошлом`.

В одной из дискуссий на очередном ресурсе программеров возник вопрос "а действительно ли это все так?"

**Пример**

Слышал, слыхал, слыхивал

**Вопросы**

1. Как это трактовать? Вариации прошедшего времени, или вариации (нескольких) прошедших времен?
2. Тот же вопрос относительно "настоящего" и "будущего"
3. Так сколько же времен в русском языке??!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В школе учили правильно: времен три. Плюс два вида, два залога, три наклонения.

Слышал, слыхал, слыхивал - разные глаголы. Корень один, но связи между ними нерегулярные, примерно как между рука, ручка и ручник. Попробуйте, например, подыскать пару по аналогии:

- Слышал - слыхал
- Дышал - ?

Нет такого слова, в этом и нерегулярность. А времена и залоги есть у всех глаголов. Вид - пограничная категория: у одних слов есть пара, у других нет, а у третьих несколько.

Comment: Sergey Slepov, доверяю, но прошу дать пруф.

Comment: Ну, посмотрите хотя бы морфологию ruscorpora.ru. Они на этом собаку съели и времен у них три: http://ruscorpora.ru/corpora-morph.html

Comment: Сергей, обязательно ознакомлюсь! Но ... наверняка быть должны действующие над-нормативные акты, которые регулируют этот вопрос?

Comment: Простой пример: идете в гос контору, и тут "въедливая" секретарша объявляет вам, что предлагаемый вами документ не может быть принят по причине "плохой читабельности" (непонятности).

Мой же вопрос простой - генерация непротиворечивых фраз (абзацев).

Comment: Если вас интересует мнение чиновников по этому вопросу, то пока, насколько мне известно, они ограничились утверждением списка словарей в качестве нормативных. Во всех этих словарях три времени. https://rg.ru/2009/08/21/russkiy-slovari-dok.html

Comment: "Генерация непротиворечивых фраз" совсем не звучик как "простой вопрос". Все зависит от определения непротиворечивости.

Comment: Сергей, огромное спасибо! Увы, я не являюсь жителем Российской Федерации, но вопрос мне действительно интересен. Хорошее объяснение, понятное! ... И наилучшие пожелания, Минск, Республика Беларусь :-)

Comment: Это, конечно же, шутка, но пара к "дышал" будет "дохнул", или даже "дыхнул". ))

Comment: Дохнул и дыхнул - совершенного вида, а слыхал - несовершенного.

Comment: сидел - сиживал, не?

Answer (score 1):

Хотя в старославянском языке и [были](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Church_Slavonic_grammar#Verbs) времена, которых в современном русском языке нет, это всё же не та ситуация. Такие глаголы называют видовыми дублетами (см., например, Сергей Карцевский, [«Из лингвистического наследия», т. 2](https://books.google.com/books?id=sanSAAAAQBAJ)) и особых времен не усматривают.

Answer (score 1):

1. Думаю, следует трактовать как разные ВИДЫ (АСПЕКТЫ) глагола.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect
 [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Вид_(лингвистика)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D0%B4_(%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0))
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Аспектология](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F)

2. Теоретически аналогично для двух остальных времён, но в русском в них виды, отличные от стандартных совершенного и несовершенного, применяются уже редко. Я имею в виду такие как ***посиживаю***, ***полёживаю***.
3. Времён три.
   Видов основных, признанных в языке, два - совершенный и несовершенный, прошедшему и будущему присущи оба вида, настоящему - только несовершенный.